# Embed a video to Facebook Post

Tags: facebook, post, video, embed, share

I have embedded a YouTube video on the index page of my website. I have a Facebook share button to share my page. I want the FB post to embed the YouTube video that's on my site but I can't get it to work. I was able to do it with twitter by using the player card. How can I can my YouTube video to embed on my FB post that is auto shared from my site?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

If you check even the facebook share on youtube.com, the videos are not embedded in the posts.